# How do we create android application custom documentation for application flow?

Tags: android, documentation-generation

Recently my team mates has started to work on an android application, which has more than 200 screens in an application.

In this case, I face one issue that when I need to explain the code or flow of screen to the other developer it would too much difficult. So I have to google to find the solution.

I am not much aware of the solution for android. In javascript, I have used jsDoc or swagger for API documentation, which offered a great way.

But in android, I unable to find the solution for coding documentation and screen flow.

Do I need any design tool to explain screen flow and documentation of an android application?

Let me know if you need more details or explanation I shall update the question accordingly or improve my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create an automated screen / state transition diagram. If you use the [Navigation Architecture component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/), you can use the navigation editor which is similar to Apple's storyboards. This is helpful but often times doesn't cover everything.

[image: Android Studio navigation editor. Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#nav-editor]

In our projects we rely on tools like [overflow.io](https://overflow.io/) to create and maintain the screen flow diagrams. We use either design files from sketch or Adobe XD or screenshots from our app. This is a very manual process.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Go to `File -> Project Structure`. Under the **Platform Settings** heading, add or **select an Android Platform**. Go to the Documentation Paths tab and make sure the path to your SDK's documentation folder is added there - it should be **[SDK]\docs\reference**, where [SDK] is the full path to your SDK installation.
If it is not found you can add it manually.
After it is completed, use `Ctrl+F1` while your cursor is on the item you want to display help for.

Comment: Yes I appreciate but I don't want to use android inbuild feature.